Why are larger numbers getting rounded off after cell change or column resize in Infragistics UltraWinGrid Cell?
I am trying to enter a large value i.e. 999999999999999.99 value in a UltraWinGrid cell which is supposed to hold an amount value.
Dim UltraGridColumn1 AS Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraWinColumn = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraWinColumn("MyAmount")

MyGrid_Initializelayout(...) handles MyGrid_Initializelayout
With e.layout
.Bands(0).Columns("MyAmount").Editor = AmountEditor
.Bands(0).Columns("MyAmount").MaskInput= "{double:15.2:c}"
.Bands(0).Columns("MyAmount").Format= "###,###,###,###,##0.00"

Private Sub myGrid_AfterExitEditMode(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal a As System.EventArgs) Handles myGrid_AfterExitEditMode
MyGrid.ActiveRow.Cells("MyAmount").Column.MaskInput = "nnn,nnn,nnn,nnn,nnn.nn"
End Sub

AmountEditor = New EditorWithMask
AmountEditor.DataFilter = New FormatAmountConverter()

Public Class FormatAmountConverter Implements iEditordataFilter
  Public Function Convert(ByVal myArgs AS Infragistics.Win.EditorDataFilterConvertArgs) As object        Implements Infragistics.Win.IEditorDataFilter.Convert
   'Some Logic
    Return CType(myArgs.Value, Double).ToString("N02")
End Function
End Class  

When I enter an amount 999999999999999.99, instead of displaying 999,999,999,999,999.99 the displayed amount is getting rounded off to 1,000,000,000,000,000.00.
When I tried to debug the code, I observed this: In MyGrid_BeforeCellActivated()...
activeCell = myGrid.ActiveCell
Here, activeCell.Value is correctly set as 999999999999999.99 while activeCell.text value is 1,000,000,000,000,000.00 which is read-only.
Is there a way to avoid rounding off this large number? While saving, the correct value is saved in the database, the issue exists within the value displayed in the grid.
Can I manipulate the amount value as soon as it is entered in an event?
Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.
When I enter an amount 999999999999999.99, instead of displaying 999,999,999,999,999.99 the displayed amount is getting rounded off to 1,000,000,000,000,000.00.

If you want that many significant figures you will need to use the Decimal type. Characteristics of the floating-point types. Also, are you saving it in the database as a string?

I am saving it in the database as decimal(18,3).

OK, so you need to use the Decimal type in your VB.NET code.

Sure, thank you, I will try using Decimal type and get back to you tomorrow.

Using Decimal type worked like a charm! Thank you @AndrewMorton
